# C# Entity Framework Commit Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a weird error when trying to call `.SaveChanges()` in Entity Framework.

I'm trying to save an `Order` like this

```
public void SaveOrder(UserDTO user, ArticleDTO article, PriceDTO price, decimal amount)
{
    //Get the order with type cart. If no order exist create a new order with type cart.
    var order = _orderRepository.GetCartOrderForCustomer(user.Customer.CustomerREFID);

    if (order == null)
    {
        order = new Order()
        {
            CustomerREFID = user.Customer.CustomerREFID,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            OrderType = OrderType.Cart
        };

        _orderRepository.Add(order);
        _orderRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

Sure its working fine when I'm only calling this method. But when I'm calling another method before this method then I get errors.

The before method just fetch articles and prices.

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticlesByCategory(int categorySection, int headCategory, string customerREFID)
{
    var currentUnitOfWork = this.UnitOfWork as MainBCUnitOfWork;

    //Linq query without keys.
    var result = (from a in currentUnitOfWork.Articles
                  join cat in currentUnitOfWork.Categories on a.CategoryID equals cat.CategoryID
                  join cf in currentUnitOfWork.CategoryReferences on cat.ID equals cf.CategoryID
                  join c in currentUnitOfWork.Customers on a.Lagstalle equals c.LagStalle
                  where cf.RefID == categorySection && cat.HuvudKat == headCategory && c.CustomerREFID == customerREFID
                  select a).ToList();

    var artnumbers = result.Select(a => a.Number).ToList();

    var prices = currentUnitOfWork.Prices.Where(p => artnumbers.Contains(p.ArtNr) && p.FtgNr == customerREFID).ToList();

    Parallel.ForEach(result, a =>
    {
        a.Prices = prices.Where(p => p.ArtNr == a.Number).ToList();
    });

    return result.ToList();

}
```

So when calling `SaveOrder` I get this error :

> {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.PriceArticles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PriceArticles'. The duplicate key value is (6653, 1).
>   The statement has been terminated.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>   ClientConnectionId:dfc62e28-3751-4a54-89f4-5fa8195cab2a}

This table and get has nothing to do with `Order` table ? Why does Entity Framework commit other tables when I only add a new `Order` ?

How do I work around this ?

Comment: This *usually* happens because the `DbContext` instance that was used to retrieve objects was disposed of and a new instance was created and then the new instance is used to perform one or more operations one entites that the instance doesn't know about so it attempts to save them back to the DB.

Comment: Is there a way to go around this because the price method returns a lot of data. And i dont want the entity framework to insert it into the database again when the data is already there.

Comment: Usually you need to "Attach" the entity to the context, depending on the EF version you're using there are various ways to accomplish this.  Here's some reading material for you (related to EF 5): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676

Comment: Tried sql profiler he runs this exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Orders]([OrderType], [CustomerREFID], [TourNumber], [CreateDate])
values (@0, @1, null, @2)
select [ID]
from [dbo].[Orders]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int,@1 nvarchar(20),@2 datetime2(7)',@0=10,@1=N'01075',@2='2012-11-28 17:20:22.8537902'

Comment: And then he runs this exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[PriceArticles]([Price_ID], [Article_ID])
values (@0, @1)
',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=6653,@1=1 this is the problem why i get the error. But why does he run this code! when it is not supposed to run